# Make a div as large as possible in flexLayout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#stack{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.spacer {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="stack">
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As the code shows above, parent had a `max-height` as the height of it is undefined.
I want the height of `spacer` was as large as possible. And what I expect is `160px` in this situation.
I had tried `flex-grow`, but it doesn't work as the container has no `height`.
I had tried `flex-shrink` and a large `height` like the code in snippet either. But I found that sometime `flex-shrink` not work, or sometimes it looks scary with a very large height.

Comment: Can you add a snippet using the snippet tool for us to test rapidly, please? Also, what have you tried and exactly what problem are you facing?

Comment: You can try with heigth: 100% or flex-grow: 1 while others items don't have it.

Comment: @Ale_info It doesn't work by using `flex-grow` because the container has not height.

Answer (score 1):

it does not work because you use a wrong selector for "stack" - it is a class, not id!
This should work: https://jsfiddle.net/bL5w81d4/1/

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.stack{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.spacer {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 1000;
}
```